# Easy way to check if object is printable

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to check if a object that was given is printable. I made this code:

```
def print_object(o):
    if isinstance(o, str):
        print(o)
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        print(o)
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        print(o)
    # go on and on...
    else:
        print("unprintable object")
```

But is there a easier way to do it with try/except? I've read something about it but cant figure it out.

Thanks a lot

EDIT:
I want to check, in the example above, if the object is a str, dict or list. If its not, than it should print "unprintable object". I've read that there is an easier way to do it with try and except but cant find it anymore. Its good to catch the errors.

EDIT2: I know that everything is printable, i just want to check if the entered number, string or whatever is "accepted" with the specifications i've given. I'm just looking for an easier way for the code above so i can use try and except.

Comment: What do you mean by printable?  Every object in python has an `__str__`, `__unicode__` or `__repr__` function that converts the object to its string representation.  All native types, bool, int, float, etc. are also printable.

Comment: I can't imagine an object *not* being printable. What would make it so?

Comment: every object in python is printable so you do not need to check if it printable.

Comment: in the example above i check if its str, dict or list. When i now have an int object, i want the function to print "unprintable object"

Comment: Why on earth do you consider an int object to be unprintable?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, all objects are "printable" since the `__str__` method is defined in `object` root class.

```
>>> hasattr(object, '__str__')
True
```

But you can define your `is_printable` predicate like this:

```
is_printable = not isinstance(o, (str, dict, list))
```

But, what about `int`, `float` or any object?

**Edit**

You **can't check** if the class explicitly define `__str__` like this:

```
is_printable = hasattr(o, '__str__')
# or
is_printable = hasattr(o.__class__, '__str__')
```

Because it is always `True`. The `__str__` method is inherited from `object` (and `type`).

But you can inspect the `__dict__` attribute (if it exist):

```
is_printable = hasattr(o, '__dict__') and '__str__' in o.__dict__
```

Comment: Why not simply : `hasattr(o, '__str__')` ?

Comment: Because it is always `True`.  `class T: pass ...  >>> t=T() >>> hasattr(t, '__str__') True`. But I just figured that it is also true for classes. So my last answer is wrong I will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `isinstance` & print in one line:

```
print(o if isinstance(o, (int,float,str,list,dict,tuple)) else "<unprintable>")
```

(I'm probably forgetting some "printable" objects, but you get the idea)